# String cannot be converted to StringBuffer

Tags: java

I am making a playfair cipher and I encountered an error that String cannot be converted to StringBuffer. How can I make my program work? Or how can I convert StringBuffer to String without compromising the code?

```
public static StringBuffer addFiller (StringBuffer input)
 {       
     for( int x = 0; x < input.length() - 1; x++)
     {
         if(input.substring(x+1, 1).equals(input.substring(x, 1)))
         {
           input = input.insert(x+1, "Q");
         }
         if("Q".equals(input.substring(x, 1)) && "Q".equals(input.substring(x+1, 1)))
         {
            input = input.insert(x+1, "Z");
         }
     }
     return input;
 }

 public static String modifyPlaintext(String keyword)
{      
    keyword = keyword.toUpperCase();
    keyword = keyword.trim();
    keyword = keyword.replace(" ","");
    //StringBuffer.toString(addFiller);
    keyword = addFiller(keyword); // error starts here and it says that keyword = java.lang.String "ALLISKNOWNFLYATONCE" even though I didn't initialize it. What does it mean?


    if (keyword.length() % 2 != 0)
        {
            keyword += "Q";
        }
        keyword = insertSpaceInSpecificNumber(2, keyword, ' ');

    return keyword;
}
```

Comment: Use: `keyword = addFiller(new StringBuffer(keyword)).toString();`

Comment: Not really to your question, but prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`. Or use a `char[]`. In what way is a `String` *compromising* here?

Comment: Unlike a `String`, a `StringBuffer` is mutable, and operations like `insert` will change the buffer.  In a statement like `input = input.insert(x+1, "Q");`, the `insert` operation changes `input`, and then it just returns the same object (i.e. `input`), which means assigning the method's result into `input` is a waste of time.  You seem to be using a `StringBuffer` the way you would use a `String`, which isn't the point of a `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder`).

Comment: @ajb what should I do? I researched that when you need to use insert, you have to use StringBuilder. So now I'm having the error of it no tbeing converted to String.

Comment: It's fine to use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, and the answers show you how to convert between those and `String`.  I'm just saying that you don't need `input =`, the way you would if you were trying to change a `String`.

Comment: Once try this..                                                                                 StringBuffer sb;
sb = new StringBuffer(keyword);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create `StringBuffer` object and pass it to `addFilter()`.

2) Convert `StringBuffer` object return by `addFilter()` into String by `toString()`.

```
keyword = addFilter(new StringBuffer(keyword)).toString();
```

Comment: It produces an error message: "String index out of range: -1"

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:908)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:76)
 at projecttrial2.ProjectTrial2.addFiller(ProjectTrial2.java:87)
 at projecttrial2.ProjectTrial2.modifyPlaintext(ProjectTrial2.java:105)
 at projecttrial2.ProjectTrial2.main(ProjectTrial2.java:47)

Comment: @CodeCodeCode It seems error is in ProjectTrial2.java at line number 87. can u post code for ProjectTrial2 class.

Comment: for( int x = 0; x < input.length() - 1; x++) 
{ 
if(input.substring(x+1, 1).equals(input.substring(x, 1)) // this is the line 87 { 
input = input.insert(x+1, "Q"); 
}
if("Q".equals(input.substring(x, 1)) && "Q".equals(input.substring(x+1, 1))) 
{ input = input.insert(x+1, "Z"); } 
}

Answer (score 1):

`String` is final and immutable too.

Hence, this class cannot be extended or inherited by any other class. So, there is no `IS-A` Relationship between these two classes. String can never be converted or referenced to any other Class except `java.lang.Object` directly.

But `StringBuffer` provides a Constructor through which you can convert a `String` into a `StringBuffer` Object.

```
public java.lang.StringBuffer(java.lang.String); //pass string as an argument. StringBuffer object will you get.
```

In your case, try this code:

```
addFilter(new StringBuffer(keyword)).toString();
```